# tukeys HSD tets for two way ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

I have been analyzing my data in R using two way ANOVA followed by Tukey HSD test. I am looking for effect of temperature and sex on development time. I was able to do two way ANOVA but having problem with post hoc test.
I used following code:

```
a <- aov(larval.time~temp*sex, mydata=R.data) #for two way anova
TukeyHSD(a) #for post hoc test
```

I got following error message for post hoc code:

```
Error in rep.int(n, length(means)) : unimplemented type 'NULL' in 'rep3'
```

In addition:

```
    Warning messages: 
 1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: Temp 
 2: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors  ignored: Temp, sex
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: You have only continuous variables in your model. Make sure that at least `sex` is a `factor` before fitting the model.

Comment: Hi, thank you. But there is only one dependent variable (larval time) in the model is continuous, while both independent factors temperature (four different temp. 18, 21, 27 and 33 degrees) and sex are categorical. Can somebody please explain me in detail how can I proceed further with post hoc test? Thank you in advance

Comment: No, that's not the case. You are mistaken. `TukeyHSD` is complaining because there are no `factor` variables in the model.

Comment: Yes figured it out, thanks a ton